# Can intellisense errors be made more readable in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to make intellisense errors in Visual Studio 2015 more readable.  I find it really hard to spot errors like this:

[image]

That's all of 3 pixels!  Can I get errors to show up in the gutter and/or change the background color like this?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are several options:

- Paid or shareware plugins like ReSharper, CodeRush, Visual Assist X etc. They do exactly what you need; e.g., highlight the error in the editor and gutter
- Freeware plugins (in addition to those already mentioned), like "Productivity Power Tools" - highlights errors in the Solution Explorer (underlines a file with error).

Comment: I have Visual Assist X, and (unless I'm missing something) there are no options to change error highlighting in any way.